# Laravel - Get route name in filter

Tags: php, laravel

How can I get current route name in filter? I tried use `Route::currentRouteName();` but it's null.

```
Route::filter('belongsToUser', function(){
    dd( Route::currentRouteName() );
    exit;
});
```

Route looks for example:

```
Route::get('/openTicket/{id}', array('before' => 'auth|belongsToUser', 'uses' => 'MyController@MyAction'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route isn't named, so it's no surprise the route name is null. You need an `as` parameter.

```
Route::get('/openTicket/{id}', array(
  'as' => 'yourRouteName',
  'before' => 'auth|belongsToUser',
  'uses' => 'MyController@MyAction'));
```

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Comment: I thought route name is "uses" value... Thank you.